# d3 rotate relate relative without coordinate

Tags: typescript, d3.js, svg, path

I append text and textPath to a path with `d3.js`. But the text is upside-down when the direction of the path is `1`. I want to rotate the text 180 degrees to correct position。 But the trahsform-origin is `(0,0,0)` and I can not get the `x,y` of the text.

How can I relative is relative without coordinate?

[image]

```
    this.link.append('text')
        .classed(className, true)
        .attr('dy', dy)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('font-size', font_size)
        .style('visibility', () => flg ? 'visible' : 'hidden')
        .append('svg:textPath')
        .classed('textPath', true)
        .classed('unselectable', true)
        .attr('xlink:href', (d) => `${this._router.url.replace('\/', '')}#${d.id}`)
        .attr('startOffset', startOffset)
        .text((d) => {
            if (!d.multi_end) {
                const value = className === 'linkUsage' ? d[valueKey]
                    ? d[valueKey] + '%' : 'N/A' : d[valueKey] ? d[valueKey] : 'N/A';
                return value;
            }
        })
        .style('fill', (d) => {
            const color = className === 'linkUsage' ? d[valueKey] ?
                this.line_service.getLinkColor(d[valueKey] / 100) : '#546e7a' : '#546e7a';
            return color;
        });
}
```

Comment: Draw the path the other way round (or in Firefox you can use the side attribute).

Comment: @Robert Longson There may be some links between two nodes,and curve is possible. I have to place them in different direction

Comment: Yes, you'd have to calculate what a path drawn from B to A looks like. That's why side is so much easier, I imagine the other browsers will catch up and implement side at some point.